# Implementing Test instead of extending TestCase in Junit [Java]

Tags: java, junit, extend, testcase, implements

I have a class C which must extend a class N because it provides functionality I must have. I want C to be a JUnit test so I want to extend TestCase, because I am using a test executor, a Junit suite object, which requires tests being added to be it to be of type TestCase. This means that I have to use the TestCase extension.

Java, however, does not allow for multiple inheritance, so I need to, instead, use an interface. Is there an existing interface? Or is there a way to dynamically execute Junit tests that don't extend from TestCase?

Comment: which version of junit are you using?

Comment: You need to use JUnit4 to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't extend `Test` or `TestCase` anymore.  I use the `@Test` annotations since version 4.4.

Comment: Obviously he is not using the new annotations API ;-)

Comment: @D.R.: Not obvious to me at all, maybe he is just used to the old way?

Comment: I adapted my answer...wasn't sure how somebody could know about unit tests but sleep away years of API evolution `*g*`

Comment: I need to dynamically create JUnit tests during run time. I need a runner object that takes in object instances and executes them; unless there's a way to do that when the instances aren't of type TestCase, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need your C class to extend N? Can't you just opt for composition instead of extension? Your C could have N as internal attribute and be using the functionalities provided by it. Just an idea.

Comment: If anything, I would first avoid inheritance between the unit tests.

Comment: No, I can't compose them; N has protected methods, and I cannot put C in the same package because I didn't write N.

Answer (score 0):

The interface is called `Test`, see: http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/Test.html

However, in newer versions of JUnit you should definitely go for the @Test attribute and add your test classes to your suite by specifying the type via `YourTestClass.class`

Comment: This *might* be what I'm looking for. Your suggestion abut @Test doesn't work because I'm trying to do something like new Test(x), new Test(y), etc.. I am dynamically creating tests at run time; I can't just specify concrete classes.

Comment: If you can't specifiy concrete classes you can dynamically specify them via reflection.